# Bootstrap form, fields on the same line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I have 3 form fields on the same line, but I can't figure out how to apply some space between them (without using margin, padding ...) I am using bootstrap 3.

This is the form:

[my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMf8G.png)

The HTML:

```
        <div class="container">
<h3>Crie seu anúncio!</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class = "panel-heading">
                    Informações de Contato 
                </div>
                <div class = "panel-body">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        id="id_{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.name }}" 
                        name="{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.name }}"
                        placeholder="Nome">
                    </div>
                    <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.help_text }} </p>
                    <br>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        id="id_{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.name }}" 
                        name="{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.name }}"
                        placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>
                    <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.help_text }} </p>
                    <br>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        id="id_{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.name }}" 
                        name="{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.name }}"
                        placeholder="Telefone ou Celular">
                    </div>
                    <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.help_text }} </p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class = "panel-heading">
                    Informações do Anúncio 
                </div>
                <div class = "panel-body">

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        id="id_{{ anuncioForm.titulo.name }}" 
                        name="{{ anuncioForm.titulo.name }}">
                    </div>
                    <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.titulo.help_text }} </p>
                    <br>

                    <label class="control-label">{{anuncioForm.tipo_anuncio.label}}</label>
                    <select class="form-control control-label" 
                    id="id_{{ anuncioForm.tipo_anuncio.name }}" 
                    name="anuncioForm.tipo_anuncio.name">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                        <option value="Venda">Venda</option>
                        <option value="Aluguel">Aluguel</option>
                        <option value="Aluguel e Venda">Aluguel e Venda</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="id_imagem_principal" 
                        name="anuncioForm.imagem_principal.name" 
                        type="file">
                    </div>
                    <p>Esta será a imagem de capa do seu anúncio</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class = "panel-heading">
                    Informações do Imóvei 
                </div>
                <div class = "panel-body">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, how could I separated the fields?

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Bootstraps Inline Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) by wrapping them inside a `<form class="form-inline">`:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class = "panel-heading">
    Informações do Imóvei 
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
        </div>         
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </form>    
  </div>
</div>
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: nozzleman, I tried it here but it does not work. Maybe it is because this only one of the panels inside a bigger form. So I think I could not use another <form>. Do you have another suggestion? All the panels are inside of <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ...

Comment: have you trid using a `div` instead of `form`-tag? what error did you get?

Comment: The image you shared is the expected result, Perfect. But I wonder why it is not working for me, that is what I keep getting (at the end of the question)

Comment: Thanks buddy ! It worked. The elements do not filled all the line, but they are separated now.

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you don't want to use padding or margin, the usual and standard way to create space between elements, but since you're using Bootstrap, you can nest the fields inside the gridsystem, as seen below:

```
<div class = "panel-body">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.titulo.label }}</label></span>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'll remind you that Bootstrap uses padding to separate each column, so you can't really get around not using it.

Comment: It does not work. The word "titulo" with grey background goes to the top of each field.

Comment: Please share the css you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS display: flex, but the padding is the property that does the job.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Informações do Imóvel 
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="input-group flex-item">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <label>Título</label>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" />
     </div>
     <div class="input-group flex-item">
       <span class="input-group-addon">
         <label>Título</label>
       </span>
       <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" />
     </div>
     <div class="input-group flex-item">
       <span class="input-group-addon">
         <label>Título</label>
       </span>
       <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" />
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Plunker Link:
[Plunker View](https://embed.plnkr.co/j87i6QTBd2pJ9IfAQ1gh/)